# C++ templated class and generics are not working

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have this:

```
template<class E, class P>
class ListenerInterface
{
public:
    virtual ListenerResponse handleEvent(E<P> *event) const = 0;
};
```

But E and P are both templated classes with default template parameters.

And I'm getting this:

```
error: expected ')'
virtual ListenerResponse handleEvent(E<P> *event) const = 0;
```

Using `cmake -std=c++14 -Wall -W -pedantic`

Comment: Well, clearly `E<P>` doesn't make sense. Like `int<double>`? Did you mean `E` to be a template? Then you should code it thus.

Comment: I mean `SomeClass<SomeOtherClass>`

Comment: What are `E` and `P` supposed to be?

Comment: E and P are supposed to be templated classes too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "minimal, complete, and verifiable" example that demonstrates not only how to resolve the immediate error, but also how to create a `Listener` class that implements the `ListenerInterface`, while satisfying the condition that:

> `E` and `P` are both templated classes with default template parameters.

First, define the classes that will correspond to `P` and `E` in this example:

```
template <typename T = int>
class Payload {
public:
  Payload (const T & value) : value(value) {}
  const T value;
};

template <typename T = Payload<>>
class Event {
public:
  Event (const T & payload) : payload(payload) {}
  const T payload;
};
```

Next, define the `ListenerResponse` and `ListenerInterface`:

```
class ListenerResponse {
public:
  ListenerResponse (const std::string & message) : message(message) {}
  const std::string message;
};

template <typename T>
class ListenerInterface {
public:
  virtual ListenerResponse handleEvent (T * event) const = 0;
};
```

Note that `template<class E, class P>` has been replaced with `template <typename T>`.

Now, define a `Listener` class that implements the `ListenerInterface`:

```
template <typename T = Event<>>
class Listener : public ListenerInterface<T> {
public:
  ListenerResponse handleEvent (T * event) const {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "Event payload value: " << event->payload.value;
    return ListenerResponse(stream.str());
  }
};
```

Then define a `main` function that puts these pieces together:

```
int main () {
  Payload<> payload(123);
  Event<> event(payload);
  Listener<> listener;
  ListenerResponse response = listener.handleEvent(&event);
  std::cout << response.message << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the full program, including the requisite `#include` statements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T = int>
class Payload {
public:
  Payload (const T & value) : value(value) {}
  const T value;
};

template <typename T = Payload<>>
class Event {
public:
  Event (const T & payload) : payload(payload) {}
  const T payload;
};

class ListenerResponse {
public:
  ListenerResponse (const std::string & message) : message(message) {}
  const std::string message;
};

template <typename T>
class ListenerInterface {
public:
  virtual ListenerResponse handleEvent (T * event) const = 0;
};

template <typename T = Event<>>
class Listener : public ListenerInterface<T> {
public:
  ListenerResponse handleEvent (T * event) const {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "Event payload value: " << event->payload.value;
    return ListenerResponse(stream.str());
  }
};

int main () {
  Payload<> payload(123);
  Event<> event(payload);
  Listener<> listener;
  ListenerResponse response = listener.handleEvent(&event);
  std::cout << response.message << std::endl;
}
```

Save the program as `example.cc`, compile it with the compiler flags that you specified, and run it to verify that it produces the expected output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -W -pedantic example.cc -o example
$ ./example
Event payload value: 123
```

Answer (score 6):

`E` is a type, not a class template, so `E<P>` is ill-formed.

Either declare `E` to be a class template by making it a template template parameter:

```
template<template <class > class E, class P>
class ListenerInterface
{
public:
    virtual ListenerResponse handleEvent(E<P> *event) const = 0;
};
```

Or simplify your interface by just taking one type:

```
template<class T>
class ListenerInterface
{
public:
    virtual ListenerResponse handleEvent(T* event) const = 0;
};
```

Comment: And how can I import the ListenerInterface definition?

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean, import?

Comment: My problem is that both `E` and `P` are templated classes. I need to do a `typedef` or a `using` on the Listener class but I don't know how.

Comment: @Daniel I have no idea what you're asking, sorry.